# How can i insert images on a slider without changing their size?

Tags: html, css, image, slider, size

I'm making a website and i'm trying to make a page with a slider. However when i put my images, they resize, staying with the slider size.

Which code can i use to block the image size?

PS: Sorry for the bad english.

Comment: i tried to put the exact height and weight of the images...and so many other things...still the same!

Comment: i changed the css code...change height and weight

Comment: i used many image properties and still nothing